# Multiple paragraphs not wrapping around left-floated elements in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I have an image and a caption in a container that float left, and I have multiple paragraphs that should be wrapping around these. I've done a jsfiddle of the basic idea, and it works everywhere I've checked except IE7 and below. And, of course, the client uses IE7.

It's such an elementary thing. It's driving me nuts! What am I missing. Many thanks in advance!!!

http://jsfiddle.net/BALUn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the style rules for `p.main` to `width: auto;` and see if that helps.

Comment: That did it. I had tried `width: 100%;` in my efforts, but it never occurred to me to set it to auto. Any idea why?

Comment: No idea why it didn't occur to you but setting 100% for width will force the element to occupy the entire width of its container. Setting the width to auto will tell it to occupy whatever space is available after taking into account borders, padding and - crucially - floated elements.

Comment: I didn't occur to me because I didn't know that. Thank you.